# Send form as ajax without re-declaring url, method etc

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm aware that if I have a form

```
<form id="poot" method="POST" action="url/toot">
    <input type="text" name="OhYeah"/>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I can do:

```
$( "#poot" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: $( "#poot" ).attr( "method" ),        
        url: $( "#poot" ).attr( "action" ),
        data: {
            OhYeah: $( "#poot" ).val()
        },
        ...        
    });
});
```

And even better (correct me if i'm wrong), you can do:

```
$( "#poot" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: $( "#poot" ).attr( "method" ),        
        url: $( "#poot" ).attr( "action" ),
        data: $( this ).serialize()             
        ...        
    });
});
```

Is there a way of just doing:

```
$( "#poot" ).submit().success( function( data ){ 
    // data returns from page
} );
```

considering this is all defined on the form html anyway...

P.S, yes I can make my own function but it'd be nice to use the jquery one (if it exists).

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. I could be wrong though.

Comment: no, that would submit the form using browser default and the `success` would not fire due to page redirect or reload. You can write a wrapper or plugin to handle many forms if that is what you are needing

Comment: Are you just trying to reduce the number of lines of code ? or was there some extra bit of functionality you were looking for ? Just wondering what's wrong with your second (even better) example ?

Answer (score -1):

```
var url = $('#poot').attr('action');
var data = $('#poot').serialize();

$( "#poot" ).submit(function () {
    $.post(url, data, function(result) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp